# Spring Retry not working with Kotlin Async Coroutine

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Note: the below function test is being called via a launch coroutine.

The following code works:

```
@Retryable(value=[RetryException::class])
suspend fun test() {
  throw RetryException("blah")
}
```

However, the moment I add an async call, retry stops working:

```
@Retryable(value=[RetryException::class])
suspend fun test() {
  val deferred = supervisorScope {
    async { library.method() }
  }
  deferred.await()
  throw RetryException("blah")
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think `await()` ends up wrapping exceptions in a `RuntimeException`.